# Vue router retain component on next

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to implement a system where a hover event over one of the navbar's links triggers the display of the desired page/component in the background, while retaining the active component in center view. The desired component only becoming "fully active" with a corresponding URL change once the user clicks on the link. I can't seem to figure out how to stop the cycle from destroying the active component while still triggering next.

Is there a way to toggle the destruction of components on/off in the hooks, like say

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
        next(vm => {
            // stop active component from being destroyed 
        })
    }
```

Much appreciated.